# Will Flash object embeds on my website be an issue for Javascript key events?

Tags: javascript, flash, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make flex only consume mouse scroll and keyboard events when it's useful, and otherwise pass it on to the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906227/how-do-i-make-flex-only-consume-mouse-scroll-and-keyboard-events-when-its-usefu)

I'm making a web application with hotkey support, but the application utilizes flash quite heavily in the form of justin.tv stream embeds. I'm worried that once a user presses play or stop or focuses the flash field in any other way it will eat all subsequent key events before they reach Javascript. I'm worried because I know that the YouTube flash field does this; once it's focused I can't close the browser window with CTRL+W or CTRL+Tab into another tab.

Is that unique to the YouTube flash player? If not, is there anything I can do on the Javascript side to make sure focus remains on my application, allowing my hotkeys to function?

Any additional information on the topic of Javascript key events and browser plugins would be appreciated.

*PS: I am aware I can deny access to the Flash field altogether by means of an invisible div overlay, but I would prefer any user to be allowed to play/stop and control the volume of the embedded stream.*

Comment: This sort of question is somewhat common.  Try the solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4906227/516537

Comment: None of the answers there are of much use to me. Two of the answers assume that I'm the one making the flash objects and the remaining answer suggests making the Flash field invisible and using a HTML front end instead, which is obviously [impossibru](http://narwhaler.com/img/f3/i/impossibru-F3Ie2V.jpg) when the Flash object is used to display video

Comment: Have you looked into [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)?  This uses javascript to control FLV for video.  If *all* you are trying to do is play video with Flash (even if it involves a playlist), then this would work.

Comment: I'm using Justin TV's embedded flash player... There really isn't an alternative

Comment: I'm really not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  Here's the thing: [Justin.tv](http://apiwiki.justin.tv/mediawiki/index.php/Live_Video_SWF_Documentation) api lets you control volume, pause/resume, etc. from within your own ActionScript 3 code.  You can develop your own controls in Flash . . . so why are you jumping outside of the Flash content to work with keystrokes?  Just implement them within your AS3 code . . . right?

Comment: My AS3 code? I have no AS3 code. My application is a HTML5 and Javascript application. I know I can also control the player using Javascript, but I was hoping to avoid creating my own controls

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail how your program works?  You feed a SWF video and control it using HTML5/JS?  Or what?  If so, and the only issue is returning control to HTML5/js if the user clicks on it, then you will **either** have to set up a Flash shell to return control, **or** else hide the Flash behind another element that will process any click/focus events and not allow the Flash to become active.  The shell, btw, would be based on the solution I posted.

Comment: I can't make such a shell since I'm working on a Linux machine and have no access to the Adobe software needed. But otherwise you are correct, but the controls are built in to the flash player. I will have to hide the controls and create my own, as well as cover up the flash field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless Flash is activated through user interaction, it doesn't receive key events. However, once it happens, it doesn't retransmit key events to DOM. Unfortunately, even though you could trap all keys in JavaScript, you wouldn't be able in general to notify Flash when you choose too. Flash won't also receive focus through tabbing, but once it has focus, will not transfer it back to the page. There are only certain key combinations that you can't listen to in Flash (because they are handled by the browser), such as Ctrl+O for example.

But if you have control over the code executed in Flash (at least, you have to be able to load foreign SWF into your own SWF), then you could pass keystrokes to it and from it. I'm not sure about the tabstops. I think it would depend on the browser and whether it allows JavaScript to call `focus()`.

Here's a [demo](http://www.lordofduct.com/blog/?p=318), it is for the right mouse click only, but it would be similar for other key/mouse events.

Comment: So the only solution is to **never** allow the user to focus the flash field in the first place? :-(

Answer (score 1):

**This solution has only been tested on Firefox on Windows.**

The main problem seems to be *removing* keyboard focus from Flash.  Setting focus *to* Flash has [some solutions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718560) already.

After some playing around, I figured out that using jQuery (latest), you can direct focus to a form's text box, which will seize the control of keyboard input from Flash.  The solution follows this process:

- `ExternalInterface` in Flash sends a command to javascript
- Javascript (using jQuery in this example) sets focus to a form text field
- Javascript removes focus from Flash (using [this SO method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3718560) to get to the Flash object)

Here is AS3 code.  (I set this up in the Flash IDE, so you will have to adjust it if using external AS3 files):

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, displayKey);

function displayKey(keyEvent:KeyboardEvent) {
    /* You can use this commented code for limiting the keys that change focus. */
    /*
    var modifier:String="";
    var keyPressed:String="";

    if (keyEvent.ctrlKey) {
        modifier="Ctrl + ";
    } else if (keyEvent.altKey) {
        modifier="Alt + ";
    } else if (keyEvent.shiftKey) {
        modifier="Shift + ";
    }

    keyPressed=keyEvent.keyCode.toString();

    // make sure to add a textfield to the stage, and name it "myTextField" to make this line work:
    myTextField.text= modifier + keyPressed;
    */

    if (ExternalInterface.available) {
        // Limit the keystrokes using javascript by using this method: 
        // ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", modifier + keyPressed );

        // Any keystroke will unfocus:
        ExternalInterface.call("sendToJavaScript", "");
    }
}
```

Sample HTML/Javascript code follows; you will need `swfobject.js` file in the same directory.  Note that the id for the Flash element is the default from the Flash IDE, and the id for the text input is `text1`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>testFocus</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            html, body { height:100%; background-color: #ffffff;}
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #flashContent { width:100%; height:100%; }
            .focus {
                border: 10px solid #00ffff;
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="outerdiv"><form id="form1">
        <input type="text" value="hmmm" id="text1">test</input>
        </form>
        </div>
<div id="flashContent">
            <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="1024" height="768" id="testFocus" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="testFocus.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#0033ff" />
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="testFocus.swf" width="1024" height="768">
                    <param name="movie" value="testFocus.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="high" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#0033ff" />
                    <param name="play" value="true" />
                    <param name="loop" value="true" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
        </div>

    <script language="JavaScript">

         $(document).ready(function() {

            // just for kicks:
            $('#text1').blur(function(){
                $(this).removeClass("focus");
            });

            // handles form's text input focus (referenced by element's id):
            $('#text1').focus(function() {
                //alert('Handler for .focus() called.');
                $(this).addClass("focus");
                removeFocusOnFlash();
            });

        });

        function removeFocusOnFlash() {

            // Find the Flash container:
            var f = $('#flashContent');

            if (f) { 
                // Hide flash:
                f.tabIndex = 0; 
                f.blur();

                f.removeClass("focus");
            }
        }

        // This is called by the Flash file:
        function sendToJavaScript(value) {

            // set focus on the form's text input field: 
            $('#text1').focus();
        }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```